# How to update material-ui-next to material-ui-latest?

Tags: material-ui

I have installed material-ui-next in my project already.Now, I want to update this version to the latest version.But, I can't find anything about this in github.Help me, thanks.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0.x Does that help? If you followed the old version of that guide which talked about `material-ui-next`, you don't need it installed like that any longer.

Comment: Working link for now: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/guides/migration-v0x/migration-v0x.md